# How to count unique records by two columns per group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Same as [How to count unique records by two columns in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023541/how-to-count-unique-records-by-two-columns-in-pandas), only per group. I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2,2], 'b':[10,10,20,30,30], 'c':[5,7,7,11,17]})
df.groupby('a').groupby(['b', 'c']).ngroups
```

And it throws `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply a function to the results of first groupping:

```
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['b', 'c']).ngroups)
#a
#1    3
#2    2
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the double groupby: Use **`drop_duplicates`** with **`['b', 'c']`** as your subset, to keep only unique rows, then groupby `'a'` and use **`size`**:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['b', 'c']).groupby('a').size()

a
1    3
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Cool solution!!

Comment: indeed cool, but I'm accepting @DYZ answer as its more straight-forward imo