# Using groupby on one column and getting unique values or count from two different columns with same attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with 5 columns out of those two columns are for ids. Its for gaming so I cannot stack them one below another. I need to groupby one column and use that to count unique values from two different columns.
Dataset is like this:-

```
Day PID1    PID2
1   xa  xs
1   xb  xa
1   xc  xv
2   xd  xb
2   xe  xr
2   xf  xe
```

I have tried multiple codes including using lambda and groupby functions in order to combine and remove duplicates but it doesn't work. I gave pd.melt method a try but it failed as well.

```
df4.groupby(['pid1'])[['Day']].values
```

I have also tried

```
df4.groupby(['Day'])[['pid1', 'pid2']].nunique
```

The result should give me the count of unique ids on a particular day. It would look something like this:-

```
Day Count
1   5
2   5
```

Comment: you mean you cannot stack both the id columns ? `df.melt('Day').groupby('Day')['value'].nunique()` ? you cant do this?

Comment: stacking would be computationally expensive for my machine, i have over 5million data points and stacking them isnt really an option

Comment: It gave me results that were off by 50k the count is around 15k and its giving 80k after computing for 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

`.ngroups` is probably what you're looking for.

Please checkout the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023749/6908282) for a similar question.

**Note:** Please check-out the question as well. There is a workaround that the OP included in the question.